# Is it ethical for a company to ask its employees to move furniture on a weekend?

Tags: professionalism, united-states, volunteering

My company (a relatively large one) recently asked for volunteers to help and move furniture to the new office on a weekend in exchange for free pizza. We are not professional movers, but people with white collar jobs who are salaried. Many of us are already on-call and work more than 40 hours a week as is.

1. Is this ethical?
2. The person who organized the event complained that not enough people volunteered. Is this a justly made complaint?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96290/discussion-on-question-by-sureal-is-it-ethical-for-a-company-to-ask-its-employee).

Comment: Something similar happened in my company in November 2017, but volunteers, all of them salaried, were given hefty bonus pay *as well as* pizza (plus an alcoholic bottle of their choice at Christmastime).

Comment: @J.G.: What did they give the teetotalers?

Comment: @Sean I was one of them. It was confusing because they asked what drink we liked without saying why, and I assumed it would be served to us there and then, so I asked for milk. In the end, I got two large two-layer boxes of chocolates.

Comment: This same situation occurred in Australia. It made national news https://www.news.com.au/news-story/fe2a0f73af792e49e20bb5462c045606

Comment: What does "relatively large" mean? Relative to what? My current company has 10 people, my last company was relatively large in comparison (50 people).

Answer (score 178, accepted):

So, they want 2,4, 6 or 8 hours work for some pizza...

And they now seem surprised that not enough people volunteered. If that is how they value your time, then I am not surprised.

They should be getting professionals in, for two reasons:

1. the professionals won't break anything and have the knowledge, equipment and skills to move heavy and/or bulky items.
2. the professionals are covered for the risks ie if they break something or hurt themselves.

So, no I would not have volunteered for this.

Edit:
For is it ethical, well some say yes and others no, but does that make any difference to the situation? I don't think it changes the question - the company asked...

When asking for volunteers, what do they mean by "volunteer"? Is it compulsory? If so, then that is not asking for volunteers. If it is not compulsory then no-one has to accept. The subsequent complaint by the company after does lead one to believe that the company expected people to come forward ie it was not truly voluntary.

This reminds me of the old chestnut about 10 men in a line and one person was asked to volunteer by taking a step forward... 9 men took one step backwards...

The consequences of error by non-professionals doing the work are also interesting. Will the insurance cover the damages when people with no training did the moving, possibly without the correct equipment? What about personal injury claims... Will there be requirements for risk assessment and HSE (or equivalent Safety Executive depending on location) procedures?

Comment: Professionals are also *fast* at moving...it's time wise always worth it to pay professionals.

Comment: When my company moved to a new location we (the employees) moved our personal computers to the new location (in the same building) during work hours on friday. A professional team of movers moved the furniture and boxes with smaller equipment to the new location at the weekend. That was okay with us escpacially because it was during work hours and the day was used to pack everything in boxes.

Comment: @some_coder "during work hours on a Friday" is not the same as coming in over the weekend for a bit of pizza... You were on your "normal" pay rate...

Comment: @SolarMike The question is whether what they are doing is ethical or not, and whether the complaint is just or not. The OP is not asking whether why should have volunteered for it or not. You have made good points, but haven't actually answered the question.

Comment: @Nisarg I suggested you are being discriminatory as you have picked on my answer and not made the same comment towards another answer that points out exactly the same... As another commenter points out, this is not really about ethics...

Comment: @SolarMike The answer from Nimesh clearly addresses both the questions listed by OP. Your "answer", while making good points, doesn't even touch upon the actual question. Having said that, there is nothing stopping you from improving your answer.

Comment: If its just regular furniture then I don't see how its any more dangerous than when anyone else asks their friends to move their stuff into their new apartment/house.

Comment: @user4574 just repeating Keith's comment below...

Comment: @user4574 it's not more dangerous than helping your friend move. Keep that in mind the next time someone asks you to move or you ask your friends to help you move to save a buck. People frequently break things or hurt themselves when moving.

Comment: I'd suggest edits to explicitly answer the two questions, about whether it was ethical to ask, and whether the complaint about low participation was just.

Answer (score 79):

> My company (a relatively large one) recently asked for volunteers

By definition it was voluntary. It wasn’t mandatory or forced upon any employee. You could simply ignore it if you didn't want to participate.

> Is this ethical?

Whether it is ethical or not could be open to debate.

> The person who organized the event complained that not enough people volunteered. Is this a justly made complaint?

As it was a volunteer job, the organiser has no grounds for making an official complaint.

They are just trying to guilt trap those who didn't participate. It couldn't be an official complaint, just a rant.

---

Some would have found it okay or maybe even fun-filled activity. Since it was just a volunteer thing and you chose as per your liking, you can simply forget about it and move on.

Comment: While it wasn't forced, the complaint afterwards certainly makes it feel like employees are being coerced into it. That makes it unethical IMHO.

Comment: "We are disappointed that there were only a few volunteers to work several hours on the weekend for **free pizza**. I mean **who does not like free pizza?**" It just seems a stupid logic for the company. That company is not valueing the employees' time and health

Comment: @M.K "...free pizza **and beer**" is a completely different story. 8P

Comment: @ForwardEd As it needs to be said, not everyone drinks alcohol (or indeed likes pizza) so these sort of offers are not very well thought out anyway.

Comment: @StephenG Pretty sure that was a joke.

Answer (score 66):

It is unethical, IMO:

- First and foremost, the fact is that any time an employer makes a request like this at least some employees are likely to feel pressured to attend because they fear that an absence will be noticed and lead to poor treatment in some way or other. Such fear may or may not be justified, but is likely to exist. Thus expecting people to "volunteer" under such circumstances is coercive and thus unethical.
- Also, the company is trying to get something of value (moving office furniture) without paying any thing close to what it's worth. (From personal experience, I know a professional moving crew makes thousands of dollars for a single day of work moving the contents of a house; I'd expect it to be (much?) more for a sizable office. Did your employer even spend $100 on the pizza?)
- Additionally, the company is trying to get that low value from its employees without really paying them - instead of moving during a normal work day and paying you for a day's work, they want you to come in on your own time and the only offered compensation is a meal (and likely not a very good one at that).
- As others have mentioned in other answers, there is the possibility that an employee could be injured in this activity. Will the company cover medical expenses if that happens? Will they pay the injured employee as if they are still working, or require the employee to take sick leave and/or go on disability leave (which may not pay the employee at his/her regular rate)? Likely these have not been thought through, but without a clear statement indicating that the company will pick up the expenses if something like that would happen, the employee can only assume that they would be the one absorbing such expenses, which is not a reasonable thing to ask by the employer. Even if the employer does pick up such expenses, asking an employee to volunteer and risk an injury isn't really reasonable or ethical, IMO.

As implied above, the company could have done more to encourage employees to attend: Pay the employees who came to help with the move or given them a day off. Another way to have "sweetened the pot" would have been to give away prizes to those who attended. Of course, they should have made clear what would happen if someone got hurt.

Addressing the issue of whether the complaint was "just": In my opinion, NO! Expecting people to give up a day of their free time to help their employer and offering nothing more than a few slices pizza is not reasonable. People do have lives outside of work and many of them aren't likely to change plans for a voluntary event at their jobs unless there's better compensation offered (or fear of reprisal for failing to come to the event). You don't say how much advance warning was given, but some people may not have been able to change their plans.

Maybe a little OT, but interestingly enough, I once experienced a sort of opposite problem: My employer of the time hired professional movers to transfer our offices from one building to a new one with more space. The move was scheduled to happen over a weekend. While we left the furniture for the movers, no one trusted them to move our computers safely. Even though we made backups, on the Friday afternoon before the move virtually everyone moved their computers themselves. While I didn't witness it personally, it became known that the VP who ran our office was livid.

Comment: "at least some employees are likely to feel pressured to attend because they fear that an absence will be noticed and lead to poor treatment in some way or other." - +1, this is *exactly* why it's unethical. You can't just wave the "oh but we were only asking" excuse around - people see past that these days. (Especially with the follow up complaint that not enough people participated.)

Comment: This is the best answer and the only one that really answers the question of whether it was ethical in a meaningful way.

Comment: In addition, the asking and subsequent complaint contribute to a hostile work environment.  This is wrong and the asker should've known better.

Comment: Why are you starting this answer with "Going against the grain"?

Comment: One of my best-paid jobs as a student was moving computers. The company moving had hired professional movers for the furniture, but they didn't trust them at all to handle the computers. So they got two dozen engineering students for that part. Beer&pizza were provided, but that was on top of a pretty decent wage.

Comment: @gerrit: When I first answered, ALL the other answers that had been posted up to that point said that it would be ethical. I'll remove that phrase now.

Answer (score 12):

There is never any harm in making an ask.

As for the pay for the work, as pizza for hours of labor is well below the minimum wage, actually that is not unethical either. The terms were stated beforehand for you to either accept or decline.

Now, I recently volunteered for a task just like this a week ago. The CEO was there. Before, he did not know who I was, and now he does. Let's say for example that there is a big important, high profile project to lead and the 2 candidates are me and someone who did not volunteer. With everything else being equal, who are they going to give it to? I'm willing to bet they will give it to the person who volunteered over the person who did not. And the advancement in that person's career from that, and the salary that goes with it, will more than make up for the few hours of your weekend.

As for the company complaining, well, are they just asking a question on why the response rate was below expectations, or are they just scolding their employees? Once again, there is no harm is asking a question.

Comment: Nathan, thank you for your response. In my opinion, this is exactly what makes it unethical. People that have preexisting medical conditions or are pregnant can not be doing this type of work. If the CEO is going to chose to promote someone that showed up over someone that potentially has a medical condition that prevents this type of work then that is wrong.

Comment: @sureal I suspect that those people could still show up and box up some papers, hold doors open for others, push a rolling chair, help direct people to the right drop-off spot, hand out drinks to their thirsty compatriots, or simply lend moral support.

Comment: This is basically a ["for exposure"](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2018/jul/09/creative-careers-is-it-ever-worth-working-for-exposure) argument, and it's not at all clear that doing free stuff "for exposure" actually helps get paid work. It's just as likely to get you pigeonholed as "the guy who doesn't mind working for free". Meanwhile, if your co-workers are trying to play the same game, you'll end up competing to see who can do the most free work, which is essentially a [dollar auction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar_auction) - worse than a zero-sum game.

Comment: (Certainly it can be good to get yourself noticed by upper management, but it's far better to do that on the clock and in ways that are relevant to the kind of opportunities you're hoping to get. If the CEO is looking to assign an important project that has to be done right, they're more likely to give it to the guy who stayed home reading a book about project management than to the guy who moved furniture.)

Comment: This is a good answer. This really is a thing. Networking is important. I know people should "prove" themselves and then the best person gets the job, but that's not how it works in the real world. For the majority of positions, the person who "can do the job" and is known through the network gets the job. Never underestimate this. It never hurts to get exposure to the higher ups, that's how I got my perm contract.

Comment: Surely "as pizza for hours of labor is well below the minimum wage, actually that is not unethical either" is not only unethical but ILLEGAL. And asking an employee to work illegally has to be unethical.

Comment: "Let's say for example that there is a big important, high profile project to lead and the 2 candidates are me and someone who did not volunteer. With everything else being equal, who are they going to give it to?" Maybe. OTOH, the next time they want something done for nothing they may remember the sucker who came in and worked for free over the weekend.

Comment: @Owain: One might think that it's illegal, but YMMV. I once tried to get my state employment agency involved when my employer was demanding an extensive amount of unpaid overtime in an area outside my expertise and job description. The agency's response was that if your salary rate is high enough and the extra work hours low enough to keep your effective hourly pay rate over minimum wage, it's not illegal; that's often not an issue for a white collar worker. In addition, it is "voluntary" in this case.

Comment: Good point, there's considerably more latitude (and expectations) of high-paid employees to do extra unpaid time.

Comment: @PieterB Networking is important, but there are lots of ways to network that *don't* involve signing up for unpaid labour. A good employer will make some effort to provide networking opportunities for their staff. Maybe I've been spoiled by working for an employer who plans for staff development, but if the only/best way to meet the guy who assigns you projects is by schlepping furniture for pizza, that seems like poor management.

Comment: @AC and if that pre-existing medical condition prevented them from attending as they required treatment at that time... for example kidney dialysis, what then?

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent but it's a fact of life that a lot of companies have poor management. Way too often it's not about how good you are at your job, but how visible you are. It sucks.

Comment: @JonP the same as if they had, say, religious obligations over the weekend -- they don't go.  My point was just that there might be other ways to contribute even they you can't do the heavy lifting.

Comment: I regret that I have but one downvote to give.

Comment: @AC This sticks them with a choice between being seen as shirking, and having to disclose their medical condition to co-workers.

Answer (score 11):

> 1) Is this ethical?

While I think it's fine to ask for volunteers to do certain difficult to outsource tasks (like decorate the office for a minor holiday event), there are numerous companies specialized in moving office furniture. I strongly believe your company was just trying to save some money here. It's not unethical to ask for volunteers if it was truly a volunteer-based, no-strings-attached, no-one-will-get-fired-for-not-volunteering event,

> 2) The person who organized the event complained that not enough people volunteered. Is this a justly made complaint?

Honestly, complaining about not getting enough volunteers for 1) a laborious task and 2) a task that benefits no one but the company during off hours is frankly very ungrateful.

I personally would not have volunteered for this task even though I enjoy volunteering in general.

Answer (score 11):

I'm currently a software developer who was once a computer repair tech, who also had to take day labor jobs in college, so I have (maybe) a unique perspective on this, as I have worked several sides of this question.

As day labor, I have helped set up cubicles and other furniture in an office environment, as well as moved furniture for large and small offices. All of this requires knowledge that most people don't have. I know this because I didn't know the "tricks of the trade" until I was in the trade. In my experience, not many people know how to safely move office furniture, let alone the electronic equipment.

When I was a computer tech, I was also hired to move electronic equipment between offices. While it was easy work for me, again, most people don't know the correct or safe way to move computers, laptops, copiers, networking equipment, etc. and then set it back up. Even in this role, we were only allowed to pack up the equipment into boxes and onto pallets. The actual moving between offices was still done by a licensed, professional, insured mover.

As a software developer, I would expect to not have to do heavy labor for my employer, unless it was an emergency, such as a networking rack or part of the building falling on someone. I.E.: someone is in danger and needs rescued. They pay me for my mind, not my muscles. I learned this the hard way, by volunteering as "the muscle" for things, then getting stuck being the "goto guy" for physical labor instead of mental labor. Most people think that if you can do physical stuff, you can't do mental stuff. Because this is often true, and the fact that employers will try to "save" money in any way, you can get pigeon-holed in a low paying job for not doing the high paying duties, even if your boss/manager/CEO is the one giving you the off-topic duties and preventing you from doing your real job.

That all said, asking you to volunteer for a labor intensive, dangerous job on the weekend is a recipe for disaster on many fronts. Not only can the equipment get damages, but also the employees. This is also taking pay away from people who do this for a living, or at least attempting to earn a living.  As such, it's not ethical.

Also, getting a pizza lunch for doing this large amount of work is a slap in the face.

As for the coordinator of this task complaining about not enough volunteers, that verges on workplace bullying. That depends on the context and manner of the complaint. If it was an offhand comment, that could just be frustration that the task they are in charge of can't be complete. If it was belligerent and badgering, then it's something much more problematic and less than ethical. It may still not be exactly unethical, but it's also not 100% ethical.

I wouldn't volunteer for this "task" and I think I'd even talk others out of it. This is one (of many times) the "not my job" statement is a reason and not an excuse.

Comment: I sure hope that if part of building falls on someone it's not up to the computer car guy but up to emergency services (in-house if a large industrial plant, external in most cases) to come and help...

Comment: @gerrit, if I'm the first one onsite, then yes, it's up to me.

Comment: You mean, as a first aider you help first until the professional medics arrive?

Comment: @gerrit, I mean that I help in emergency situations until my help is no longer necessary. If the emergency response crew can use my assistance and I'm still able to give it (as in being uninjured enough to continue to help), I will give it.

Answer (score 6):

Is not ethical at all, in fact it is dangerous.

This young friend died moving furniture:

https://vejasp.abril.com.br/cidades/aluno-usp-morre-asfixiado-armario-poli/

Answer (score 4):

Yes.   Of course.    I've had to not only move furniture in the building, but I have actually had to box up my stuff and move it to a new building, despite being a "white collar employee", in my own car.

Don't want to do it?  Don't.   But if you're not doing anthing, it's a great way to make friends with your coworkers, get a free meal, and look good for the boss.

Comment: Did you just say that a meal obtained while going to the workplace on the week-end and moving stuff for your company is *free* !?

Comment: Where are you based? Boxing up your stuff and moving it to a new building is one thing, but coming in for free on the weekend and moving large items of furniture is a whole different story. I don't know anyone here (UK) that would dream of doing that for a large company. Never mind "free meal", if they wanted me to work on the weekend I'd be expecting overtime pay, not skimping out by just throwing 10 bucks on a pizza.

Comment: Pizzas are only effectively free in such scenario if their value is significantly higher than value of one or two workdays. Or more for people that value work-life balance above hourly pay. I really hope and expect that for most people such pizza wouldn't be free, but rather one of their most expensive meals.

Comment: It's like the guy who offers to buy pizza for friends helping him to move his apartment.   Can a few slices of pizza repay the time?  No.  But it's about being a friend, helping out, being part of the gang.   If you're not interested in it, don't help.   If you have no desire to give your company more than a penny's worth of free work, that's your call.   But from a career standpoint, it's often a good idea to show up.    Just the way it is.

Comment: We're being hasty in our assessment of the pizza-value equation. Perhaps it was loaded with white truffles & wagu beef, and was indeed worth an equivalent to several hours of pay.

Comment: Any commodity that you don't necessarily *pay* for, but have to instead spend a large amount of personal time and effort to obtain is, is definitely not **free**. As they say, `time is money`.

Comment: @Keith No, that's a completely false analogy. I'd help friends move for pizza because they're my *friends*, I enjoy hanging out with them, and they'd help me do the same a few months down the line if need be. My *employer* is not my friend, they certainly wouldn't help *me* move for a pizza, and if you think a day at the weekend counts as nothing more than a penny's worth of free work, you seriously undervalue your time off.

Comment: @Graham I found the pizza! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3tQ7OyLFnA

Comment: @berry120   And to many, their friends are the people they work with.   Maybe your job is not one you care about, but I've had some jobs in the past where I genuinely cared if they succeeded or failed beyond the paycheck, and was willing to give a few hours of my own time.   My current employer is a family owned business, and they've been good to me.  I'd give a few hours in that type of situation if asked.   Why is that concept so crazy?

Comment: @Keith Your assertion that I can't care about my job because I won't work for a free day on the weekend is, quite frankly, ludicrous. Let me flip your concept on its head - why is it so crazy to think that a business (that you claim is good to you) would pay a few extra bucks to get professional movers in, instead of expecting employees to work for free?

Comment: @berry120  Didn't say that.  I'm saying you don't have the same level of commitment that one might if they're willing to take a personal involvement.    Even your response to me here is indicative of it.  I'm not saying you're a bad person for it, or that it's a bad thing.   But your attitude seems to be that unless you get paid specifically for that task, it doesn't get done by you.  Again...that's ok.   But when they are looking for "team players" to promote, or to give special tasks to, don't be surprised if it's one of the folks that did care enough to help move stuff for pizza.

Comment: @Keith You implied exactly that, you just changed it to "commitment" in your latest reply instead. In any case, if a company are looking for "team players" to promote, and they base that on who came in for free on a Saturday to move heavy furniture, rather than performance and dedication to your *actual* job, that's not a company that's going to last very long. It's also a company that any decent employees will likely leave very quickly.

Comment: @berry120 does it not make sense that dedication and performance can actually be measured by who is willing to give a bit of their off hours to the company?    But even throwing that out...would you go golfing (assuming you golf) with the boss if he asked you to on a Saturday morning?     Why or why not?   Do you believe it would benefit your career at all to do it?   Of course it would.  Same thing.      More familiarity with the guy in charge never hurts.    Whether golfing or moving boxes.

Comment: @Keith No, that doesn't really add up in practice. I've met *terrible* employees that always worked overtime but just couldn't get anything valuable done, and brilliant employees that did 5 times as much in just the hours they were paid for. And no, I wouldn't golf with the boss on a Saturday morning, I'd much sooner keep my personal & private life separate. Again, I'd much sooner shine and get promoted *for the work I'm paid to do*, not by cosying up to upper management. If that doesn't work at my current company, I'd go some place else.

Comment: @berry120  That is wonderfully naive of the way the world works.   It sounds great in theory, though.

Comment: @Keith Golfing with the boss is a very different scenario. It doesn't involve doing unpaid work.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent but it does actually involve spending your "off time" with people from work.   And often involves discussing work.

Comment: @Keith yep, but it's much more of a mutual-benefit proposition than furniture-moving. That said, while far less exploitative, it's still problematic if that kind of out-of-hours activity is important to promotion etc. - it can end up being indirect discrimination against people who can't participate.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent there is no indication that this sort of thing is any kind of a regularly occurring thing or that they make a habit of using and abusing the employees in that manner.  I understand it to be a question of MAYYYYYYYYYYYBE once a year type of thing.   Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 4):

- It is ethical to ask employees to do minor jobs which are **not part of their job description.** Employers can ask an engineer to answer the phone and take messages for the boss if nobody else is in the office, they can ask a programmer to talk to customers as a sales rep, and so on.
  The two requirements are that the job truly is *minor* in relation to other tasks (it wouldn't be fair to turn an engineer into a full-time receptionist) and that the employee can do it competently (if the programmer is supposed to sell the product, he needs a competent briefing on what to promise/sign and what not).
  It is OK to refuse to move heavy desks, it is not OK to refuse to move files in easy-to-carry batches.
- It must be understood that these minor jobs are **part of the paid worktime.** This can be tricky for employees with no fixed hours, but even these employees have a general understanding just how much work they are supposed to do. The minor jobs count against this understanding.
  The employer is free to offer extra pizza at unusual working hours, but that should not be seen as the 'salary' or 'compensation' for the work. It is a morale-building **bonus**.
- It may be understood that sometimes **work is done on weekends**, or not. Moving stuff on a weekend is no different from finishing a project on a weekend.

Answer (score 3):

So long as it is truly voluntary, I don't see any ethical problems.  I'd characterize it more as a risky request.  What some see as a team building opportunity, others see as pressure to do what they don't really want to do when they really don't want to do it.

People can complain about whatever they want.  If the organizer's complaints are crossing the line to coercing people to do something outside of their job function, then yes it's crossed into an unreasonable case.

Answer (score 2):

### 1st question: It is ethical. Only unprofessional. May ring an alarm bell.

### 2nd question: No, it's unjust, unethical, and must ring an alarm bell.

1st: Although a true professional company would never ask such a thing, some rapidly growing companies, while trying to be professional, may act completely unprofessional. As long as it works for both sides, it's up to you to join it.

Back in time, I was doing things not in my jobspec, overtime, moved heavy furniture as few minute-work... But, when I was moving my own flat, I was given the company car. I took last-minute dayoff's.

But beware: This type of companies most likely do their all other professional work with the same unprofessional approach, and sooner or later this unprofessionalism may reflect your actual tasks, beyond you can tolerate.

2. No, no. This is unacceptable. No company that claims being professional would put such pressure. Expect the same approach when it comes to bonuses, dayoffs and other HR related issues.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the company culture, moving can make a good team-building event. In this case, pizza payment is adequate and can even be supplemented unofficially with a bottle of beer.

It may equally well not fit in the "team-building" frame.

Comment: You don't mention what country you're in. In the US the combination of "team-building", "white-collar", "furniture moving", and "bottle of beer" would not fly for even a second.

Comment: @BobJarvis I'm in the US and you're overstating your case. It's not unthinkable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all of the other answers, with one caveat -- if this was "just plain office furniture", yeah -- hire movers. The other caveat is "small startup", but the OP said this is a large company.

The only instance where this makes remote sense is when what's being moved aren't things which can readily be dumped in boxes, taped, tossed on a truck, hauled in, and dumped in a new workspace. For example, I once moved $2M worth of computer equipment in a co-workers pickup truck ... after hours, at night, off the loading dock (no, really) ... because we couldn't count on "the movers" to not break everything.

The other instance, which is completely unethical, is where "volunteers" are rewarded with "first dibs" on the best spaces.

TL;DR - Large companies should only rely on "volunteer movers" for specialized items which require specialized skills. Small companies may ask for "volunteer movers". "Volunteers" shouldn't be given special rewards, like choice office space.

Comment: Specialized items requiring specialized skills should have specialized movers.  While you may know some of the special usage information, you aren't a mover.  If this is important to the business, it should be important enough to hire qualified individuals.

Comment: I believe it was intended to mean, with special equipment as in, weird lab prototypes, or experimental things that only the person(s) who built it would know about...in that case, they'd be the most qualified to deal with taking such a thing apart and moving to another place....

Comment: @morbo not so sure, there are many instances of users of things who have **no** clue how to repair, mainitain, move or store them properly. As an example look at the drivers of cars...

Comment: @SolarMike those people are not the ones i mentioned.

Comment: Usually you would have a plan of where everything(& everyone) is moving to before you move (to prevent cherry picking like that). Otherwise it's just a bun fight!

Comment: *"I once moved $2M worth of computer equipment in a co-workers pickup truck \[...\] because we couldn't count on "the movers" to not break everything."* So what would have happened if you damaged something, or someone swerved through an intersection (or whatever) and hit your coworker's pickup truck?

Comment: @aCVn - The same thing as if aliens had come down from outer space and eaten us all alive. The risk of anything at all going wrong, in the middle of the night, the way it was handled, was infinitely less than having "movers" move our lab. It's not like we didn't move our own things all over the place when we weren't moving buildings. Being a software engineer isn't all sitting at a keyboard and staring at cat GIFs ...

Answer (score -3):

They asked you to voulunteer.  They are not forcing you do it so its not unethical.

Voulunteering shows that you value the success of the company, which may make a good impression on your boss.

Also if you help participate in the setup then you might get to have some input on where everything goes.

If its just regular furniture then I don't see how its any different than when anyone else asks their friends to move their stuff into their new appartment/house.

Comment: It's different than helping a friend move to a new home because it's your employer. They have control over promotions, salary, and even whether you continue to be paid.

Comment: As someone who has worked white collar jobs as well as the professional mover, moving office furniture is fundamentally different than moving your home furniture, especially if they are moving the cube walls. Even moving free standing desks is different than a couch/sofa/bed, as they are likely much heavier and require a special lifting jack to make it safe. Also, preventing the load from shifting in the moving truck is very different with 50 rolling office chairs vs anything else, since untrained people won't realize how much they move.

Comment: @GreenMatt And of course there's no expectation of reciprocity here - if OP needs to move house, the CEO isn't likely to show up to help with that.

Comment: "Voulunteering shows that you value the success of the company, which may make a good impression on your boss" If the success of the company hinges on them not having to pay professional movers for a day's work, then it's a company you're best out of ASAP.

Comment: @berry120 They didn't say that the success of the company depended on it. If you have to make up details, then just stop.

Comment: @KevinBeal Again, it's implied, and again, you're nitpicking. I've explained at some length why I believe your take on this to be completely wrong on your original answer (which you've since deleted) - I'm not going to have a rehash of that same discussion here. Continue with others if you wish, I'm bowing out at this point.

Comment: @berry120 It's not implied, and I'm not nitpicking. If you're wrong about that, it is fatal to the logic of your statement.